# How can I send a value from a checkbox switch to a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My Code:

**HTML**

```
We change switch from on to off

    <div class="switch">
<label>
Off
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="lever"></span>
On
</label>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

We send data

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {
    var status = status;

    if (status) {
    var value = "1";
    } else {
    var value = "0";
    }
    $.ajax({
    url : 'push_send/send_register.php',
    type : "post",
    data : { status : value}
    })
    });
```

**PHP**

We capture data

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['status']);
  if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbl_config SET register='" .$name. "'"));

} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

*But the values ​​are not saved, can you help me to make the code work?*

> Please Help

Comment: use `.is(':checked')` to get if checked or not

Comment: .is instead of .find?

Comment: no need to change find(), just use `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {` like so

Comment: thank you my king, it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: You realize that you're updating your entire database; is that what you want to do? @Bryan

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1):

Here you have not assigned any value for your checkbox so it's default value will be 'on'.
Considering this your code will looks like this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (){
  let status = $(this).val();
  if(status === 'on')
   status ="1";
  else
   status ="0";
          
  $.ajax({
    url : 'push_send/send_register.php',
    type : "post",
    data : { status : status}
  });
});
```